# How to remove white space and + sign from url in php

Tags: php, regex

I am sending an array through URL. My problem is I need to remove all whitespace and plus signs from the array.

my URL: `http://check.php?phnno=+123 35,+321 425,+9898 9898`

I've done this:

```
$phnno = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_REQUEST['phnno']);
$phn = (explode(",",$phnno1));
```

Now it's removing all whitespace. I need to remove `+` signs too.

Comment: Serialize the array and use urlencode()

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code it may help you ,

```
$url  = "http://check.php?phnno=+123 35,+321 425,+9898 9898";
$url  =  str_replace("+","",$url);
echo $url;
```